# htaccess rewrite rules need improves

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

i have some framefwork with **/application**, **/system**, **/public** folders, and index.php located in public folder.

To access site need use link - `http://example.com/public/index.php`

But i want use link - `http://example.com/` which load from `/public/index.php`

I found some rewrite rules for htaccess to resolve this

/.htaccess in Root Dir:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

/public/.htaccess in Pub Dir:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
<Files .*>
    Require all denied
</Files>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [PT,QSA,L]
```

It's rewrite all queries to `/public/index.php` (and work fine), but need some improve:

Assets files in public dir can be load directly by link - `http://example.com/public/css/style.css`, but how we can remove public word from url for clean look?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: if public is the root directory in index.php move into that folder i.e `chdir('./public')` then just remove `public/` from code.

Comment: I suggest for you to set document_root to public directory and that you don't need htaccess rewrites

Comment: "Assets files in public dir can be load directly by link - `http://example.com/public/css/style.css`" - If you are going to remove "/public" from your _page_ URLs then why not remove `/public` from _all_ your URLs? (By keeping `/public` in URLs to static assets then you are still _exposing_ that subdirectory.)

Comment: @AdamP. Changing the `DocumentRoot` won't resolve the OPs issue if they still have `/public` as part of the URL to their static assets (as they have stated).

Comment: @LawrenceCherone "move into that folder i.e `chdir('./public')`" - The OP is rewriting the URL in Apache, what does this have to do with `chdir()`?

Comment: @PlayerKillerYKT I think (based on directory names) you used an earlier version of Codeigniter 4. Is it right?

Comment: @AdamP. No, i use latest fork of "Blue Flame" for php 8.0)

Comment: "but how we can remove public word from url for clean look?" - You remove "public" from the URL by actually removing "public" from the URL in your internal links. Are you already doing that? This isn't something you do in `.htaccess`, except to preserve SEO if changing an existing URL structure.

Comment: @MrWhite i can remove "public" word from url only in my localhost machine(Apache 2.4), but if u upload site in hosting(they use Apache too) i can't remove "public" from url for assets files, because i have error "route not found" by my framework, this mean query passed to public/index.php instead of direct access to assets files. I don't know why, maybe wrong or not complete rules in htaccess or what?

Comment: @PlayerKillerYKT Can you share a link from original project which you forked?

Comment: @AdamP. Yes - https://github.com/modseven/core

Comment: @PlayerKillerYKT This project based on Koseven which based on Kohana which is a deprecated framework, last update at 2016...

Comment: @AdamP. Yes, and Kohana it's renamed Blue Flame fork of Code Igniter, Koseven just fix some Kohana problems with php 7, but Modseven it's fully reworked framework for use latest technologies of PHP and PSR recomendation

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify htaccess file in root directory to this (**change "domain-name.com" to your domain name**):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

And this file in the public directory I think is unnecessary